# Make IIS fetch Default Web Site using ::1, not only using 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, iis, localhost, ipv6

After installing IIS 10.0 and creation of simple test page, I can access that page by using `127.0.0.1` or by using `localhost`. How can I make the same page accessible via `::1` (what is IPv6 localhost)?

I added a site binding of IIS `Default Web Site` to `::1` like this:

[image]

I also tried

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

and

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::1
```

But entering `::1` into browser address bar just launches web search of `::1`.
Command `ping ::1` returns time `<1ms` so it looks like ::1 is working normally.

I checked numerous online guides but I cannot find this addressed.

Comment: Because your browser expects you use `[::1]`. `::1` is invalid for many browsers (like Firefox).

Comment: @LexLi – I see you are right. I did not know that. It works even in default config, no changes required. Just kindly add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP v6 address convention is so unique that many browsers like Firefox require you use `[::1]` explicitly. Since `::1` is not considered an IP v6 address in address bar, such browsers will perform a search instead, which matches your observation.

BTW, you don't need an explicit site binding for IP v6 address on IIS. The default `*` binding handles both IP v4 and v6 traffic.